# Why are the domains https.lk , ftp.lk and http.lk restricted on the Sri Lanka domain registry

Tags: phishing, domain

I found http://nic.lk which is the domain registry for .lk domains (I am in Sri Lanka).I typed in **https.lk** and it said

> 'https.lk' Domain name you searched is restricted.

Why is this done. Is it to prevent phishing from someone doing something like **https.lk/facebook.com**. But there seems to be a domain called **https.com** which is already taken.

Why doesn't Sri Lanka allow the domain **https.lk**

Also the same for **http.lk** and **ftp.lk**

Comment: I imagine the reason this registrar does this can only really be answered by them.

Comment: Most likely not because of security but because they know it's an important domain and prefer to keep it for themselves to eventually give it to the highest bidder.

Answer (score 1):

TLDs (top level domains) are allowed to have certain restrictions based on location, the type of content, and the domain names.

It is not surprising that they'd block it to avoid confusion on the domain name's owner which would appear to many as being the same as `.lk`.